# suggestions for a 3D graph rendering library?

Tags: java, graph, 3d

So I'm not sure how stackoverflow friendly this question is since it doesn't have a quick clear cut answer but here we go...

I have a java program that generates data for a directed graph. Now I need to render this graph. The data needs to be laid out in 3D, and I want to be able to define which plane an edge lives in. (Each edge will only need to occupy 1 plane of the 3D space). I also need the ability to navigate around the graph. Since I know that this kind of stuff is hard, I'm going shopping.

So far I've looked into (In no particular order):

- JUNG: *lacks 3D support*
- Cytoscape: *not sure how much I'll be able to define edge drawing, haven't seen a non bio-informatics application of it yet*
- JGraph: *I didn't see any 3D applications yet*
- Perfuse: *looks promising, does anyone know anything else about it?*
- Gephi: *Documentation looks scarce*
- Processing: *does this play well with java?*

I'm also considering doing some combination of opengl + swing rendering to create a 3D graph from multiple 2D graphs.

I am also not adverse to the idea of linking from another language

Any Ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using Java3D for the visualization part

- [Java 3D Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/java3d/index.html) Introduces the concepts
- [Download Site](https://java3d.dev.java.net/binary-builds.html) contains the libraries and a few demo projects, for a quick start.

To do the layout of your graph you could look for an algorithms in [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/applet/index.html)  and check whether the can be easily  extended to 3D.

[JUNG layout demo](http://jung.sourceforge.net/applet/showlayouts2.html)

- [A link collection on graph layouts](http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/open-source-graph-network-visualization-in-java/view)

Comment: I ended up going a different route but this is the closest. Since we're doing a lot of custom stuff, we're going to be combining a couple different techs.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few 3D graph visualizers out there.

The 3D viewers I know of are:

1. [UBIGraph](http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/) - the [demos](http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/content/Demos/index.html) page has some nice animations on it.
2. [Wilmascope](http://wilma.sourceforge.net/) - opensource and written in **Java3D**

Since wilmascope is opensource if the layouts don't suit you you could extend it to meet your requirements maybe. Laying out a graph in 3D is not easy however.

You could also take a look at [Cuttlefish](http://cuttlefish.sourceforge.net/) on sourceforge. There's a [video on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLGtNPDflcw) showing an example of it being used.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to consider python. matplotlib from python. You will probably have to output your data to an intermediate format and run a python script on the data because matplotlib has  cpython bindings, but the library have some great features for graphing and reporting.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about using matplotlib, do you know off the top of your head if it has support for custom layouts? (As I'll probably need)

Comment: as far as I know it allows for any kind of layout you like but I might be using it "inside the box" so perhaps I have just not encountered any layout issues that you might run into.

Answer (score 0):

I've played with Processing and OpenGL [last term](http://doc.gold.ac.uk/~ma802gp/abstract).
Not sure if drawing 2D planes is the best approach.
But you can make certainly draw your graph points in 3d using Processing
if you want to. Here is an applet from [openprocessing](http://www.openprocessing.org/visuals/?visualID=7098).

We studied signal processing a bit and we used [Octave](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/octave3/octave%5F159.html) and [GNUPlot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) to plot signals
in 2d(using plot, stem, etc.) and 3d(using mesh)

[image: octave mesh]
<sub>(source: [network-theory.co.uk](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/octave3/mesh.png))</sub>

I've googled for java gnuplot and seemed to found some handy links...

Check out the Java links on [GnuPlot Programming Interfaces](http://www.gnuplot.info/links.html), like:
[this](http://www.is.informatik.uni-duisburg.de/projects/java-unidu/api/de/unidu/is/gnuplot/package-summary.html),[javaplot](http://gnujavaplot.sourceforge.net/JavaPlot/About.html), [jgnuplot](http://jgnuplot.sourceforge.net/), etc.

For some hardcore graphin' be it 2d or 3d, gnuplot seems to be a pretty powerful choice.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have coordinate data. Instead I just have a list of which nodes are pointing to which other nodes. Do you know if any of those tools will do that for me?

Comment: Sorry, I understood something else by 3d graph rendering :)
Is this closer to what you're looking for? 
http://www.openprocessing.org/visuals/?visualID=2049

Answer (score 0):

take a look at Java vtk.  vtk is a complex beast, but very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

[NAViGaTOR](http://ophid.utoronto.ca/navigator/) lets you fix nodes in different 3D planes. So if you fix the adjacent nodes of an edge in the same plane, then the corresponding edge will be in that plane too. However, it doesn't support directed edges - you'll just get an undirected representation of your graph.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try http://code.google.com/p/jzy3d, which will really help you to do what you want. It's a java library for rapidly plotting surfaces, scatters and 3d primitives (spheres, lines, points, etc).
Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

[VisAD](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~billh/visad.html)

> VisAD is a Java component library for interactive and collaborative
>   visualization and analysis of numerical data. The name VisAD is an
>   acronym for "Visualization for Algorithm Development". The system
>   combines:
>
> - The use of pure Java for platform independence and to support data sharing and real-time collaboration among geographically distributed
>     users. Support for distributed computing is integrated at the lowest
>     levels of the system using Java RMI distributed objects.
> - A general mathematical data model that can be adapted to virtually any numerical data, that supports data sharing among different users,
>     different data sources and different scientific disciplines, and that
>     provides transparent access to data independent of storage format and
>     location (i.e., memory, disk or remote). The data model has been
>     adapted to netCDF, HDF-5, FITS, HDF-EOS, McIDAS, Vis5D, GIF, JPEG,
>     TIFF, QuickTime, ASCII and many other file formats.
> - A general display model that supports interactive 3-D, data fusion, multiple data views, direct manipulation, collaboration, and
>     virtual reality. The display model has been adapted to Java3D and
>     Java2D and used in an ImmersaDesk virtual reality display.
> - Data analysis and computation integrated with visualization to support computational steering and other complex interaction modes.
> - Support for two distinct communities: developers who create domain- specific systems based on VisAD, and users of those  domain-specific systems. VisAD is designed to support a wide variety
>     of user interfaces, ranging from simple data browser applets to
>     complex applications that allow groups of scientists to
>     collaboratively develop data analysis algorithms.
> - Developer extensibility in as many ways as possible.

Comment: This looks more like a plotting library.